# NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor

Tags: java, web, service, jax-rs

I have created simple REST endpoint API interface using JAX-RS annotations:

```
package pl.webservice.cards;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/cards")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface CardsServiceApi {

    @GET
    @Path("/message")
    public String getMessage();
}
```

And its implementation:

```
package pl.webservice.cards;

public class CardsService implements CardsServiceApi{

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

After sending request in POSTMAN I receive following response:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor
>   in pl.webservice.cards.CardsServiceApi class.

What is interesting when I "merge" both classes in non-interface class everything works fine. Why?

Comment: What's your JAX-RS implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is, that the REST-Annotations are in an interface. The server tries to instantiate the interface, which is not possible. If you move the annotations to the implementation class, erverything should work.

Comment: Seems logical :) Thanks

Comment: The annotations can be on the interface. Just the `@Path` needs to the on the concrete class. The `@Path` classes are what Jersey will try to instantiate. But it is perfectly legal, to have all the other JAX-RS annotations on the interface.

Comment: I think it is not the better solution. The book "Restful Java with JAX-RS 2.0" says : "no JAX-RS annotations are needed within the implementing class. All
our metadata is confined to the interface".I think that it is correct, because of this way you can seperate the logical of the control and the annotations. It is a good practice because it any moment you could deploy the same control like Jax-RS, Jax-Ws, etc only implement a different interface (or or both)